# Can't access methods of an object?

Tags: java, inheritance, interface, casting, polymorphism

I have a small example where I have an interface as below

```
public interface Chair {
    int getHeight();
    String getType();
    int getPrice();
}
```

And a class:

```
public class ExpensiveChair implements Chair {
    private int height;
    private int price;
    static private String type = "Expensive";

    public ExpensiveChair(int height, int price){
        this.height = height;
        this.price = price;
    }

    public void setHeight(int height) {
        this.height = height;
    }

    @Override
    public int getHeight() {
        return this.height;
    }

    @Override
    public String getType() {
        return this.type;
    }

    @Override
    public int getPrice() {
        return this.price;
    }
}
```

But if I do something like

```
Chair chair = new ExpensiveChair(1, 2);
```

I can't call

```
chair.setHeight(5)
```

I need to typecast it first?

```
((ExpensiveChair) chair).setHeight(1);
```

Why do I need to cast it explicitely or I can't call the method?

Comment: Because the type `Chair` does not have a method `setHeight`. Only `ExpensiveChair` does

Comment: @QBrute So essentially it doesn't know that the object is of type ExpensiveChair before runtime? Because if I do something like chair.getClass then it shows ExpensiveChair, but I guess it happens during runtime

Comment: It's not that. It's because you say that the created instance is of type `Chair`. Imagine you had another class `CheapChair` also extending `Chair`, but without a `setHeight` method. You could do `Chair chair = new CheapChair();`. Then what would `chair.setHeight(5)` do?

Comment: @QBrute Well it could see that the object is CheapChair, see if it has a method ```setHeight``` and then act accordingly?

Comment: This is not how it works. At the time you declare a variable with the static type `Chair`, you can only call the methods you defined in the `Chair` interface on that instance. The only thing you could do would be to add a `setHeight` method to the `Chair` interface, or cast it to the more specific type `ExpensiveChair` like you already did

Comment: @QBrute thank you.

Answer (score 1):

When you create the object `Chair chair`, Java reads it as a `Chair` object, even if later you assign it to `ExpensiveChair`. So, you can only access methods in `Chair`. Since `Chair` doesn't have the method `setHeight()`, only `ExpensiveChair` does, it complains.

I saw in the comments that you said "Because if I do something like chair.getClass then it shows ExpensiveChair." That is because during runtime, it calls all the method of `ExpensiveChair`, and it calls `ExpenisveChair`'s `getClass()` method. But during **compile time** it reads it as a `Chair` object.